# Passing a vector into the window argument of Pandas rolling_mean()

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate the rolling mean of a time series but using a list of different window sizes.

Indeed, I can use a for loop to achieve this like so:

```
def rolling_mean(series, *vals):
    for i in vals:
        m = pd.rolling_mean(series, window=i)
        print (m)
```

However I would like to instead try and find a vectorized method which would utilize Pandas' functionality better. Initially I would have imagined something like this would have been perfect:

```
def rolling_mean(series, *vals):
    df = pd.rolling_mean(series, window=vals)
    print (df)
```

where the above method would return a DataFrame object of rolling means of varying window lengths of the series argument. Unfortunately the rolling_mean() window argument only accepts integers. I cannot think of any other way to achieve this.

Is there a vectorized way to pass the *vals values into rolling_mean()?

Comment: I think your first way is best.  Even if the second way could be made to work (not easily I don't think) it wouldn't really be vectorized, only having the appearance of it.  If you really want to vectorize this you'd have to do it explicitly by re-writing rolling_mean, or rolling your own with numpy, numba, cython, or similar.  Doubtful it would be worth it though.

Comment: I left it as in the first example, at least for now and maybe hopefully someone may find an answer. It would be interesting to find a solution for this, but I guess the for loop does the job anyway. Thanks for your insight!

Answer (score 1):

Say for example you want to calculate the rolling mean over `windows = [20, 40, 60, 80, 120, 250]`

```
#create a new dataframe
rolling_means = pd.DataFrame()

windows = [20, 40, 60, 80, 120, 250]
labels = ['20', '40', '60', '80', '120', '250']

for window,label in zip(windows, labels):
    rolling_means[label] = pd.rolling_mean(series, window = window)
```

This will create a dataframe with each column being the different rolling mean.

all you would need to do to trim the data so that is has full data points for comparison is:

`rolling_means.dropna(how = 'any', inplace=True)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is still making use of the for-loop though isn't it?

Comment: How many different windows are you looking at here? if it is only a few you're not getting much of a performance boost.

Comment: Yes you are right. I guess the amount of windows is not that significant to consider vectorising. The method may take any number of arguments, however I cannot imagine an application which would require hundreds of moving averages, so the performance boost won't really make a difference.

Comment: you can check by using the %timeit magic in python and seeing how long the loop takes. If it is something that you can live with than it may not be worth vectoring.